# When $n$ is divided by $14$, the remainder is $10$. What is the remainder when $n$ is divided by $7$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education

**I need to explain this to someone who hasn't taken a math course for 5 years**. She is good with her algebra.

This was my attempt:

> Here's how this question works. To motivate what I'll be doing,
>   consider  \begin{equation*} \dfrac{5}{3} = 1 + \dfrac{2}{3}\text{.}
> \end{equation*} This is because when 5 is divided by 3, 3 goes into 5
>   once (hence the $1$ term) and there is a remainder of $2$ (hence the
>   $\dfrac{2}{3}$ term). **Note the following: every division problem can
>   be decomposed into an integer (the $1$ in this case) plus a fraction,
>   with the denominator being what you divide by (the $3$ in this
>   case)**.
>
> So, when $n$ is divided by 14, the remainder is 10. This can be
>   written as  \begin{equation*} \dfrac{n}{14} = a + \dfrac{10}{14}
> \end{equation*} where $a$ is an integer.
>
> We want to find the remainder when $n$ is divided by 7, which I'll
>   call $r$. So \begin{equation*} \dfrac{n}{7} = b + \dfrac{r}{7}\text{,}
> \end{equation*}  where $b$ is an integer.
>
> Here's the key point to notice: notice that  \begin{equation*}
> \dfrac{n}{7} = \dfrac{2n}{14} = 2\left(\dfrac{n}{14}\right)\text{.}
> \end{equation*} This is because $\dfrac{1}{7} = \dfrac{2}{14}$.
>
> Thus, \begin{equation*} \dfrac{n}{7} = 2\left(\dfrac{n}{14}\right) =
> 2\left(a + \dfrac{10}{14}\right) = 2a + 2\left(\dfrac{10}{14}\right) =
> 2a + \dfrac{10}{7} = 2a + \dfrac{7}{7} + \dfrac{3}{7} = (2a+1) +
> \dfrac{3}{7}\text{.} \end{equation*} So, since $a$ is an integer, $2a
> + 1$ is an integer, which is our $b$ from the original equation. Thus, $r = 3$.

To her, this method was not very intuitive. She did understand the explanation. Are there any suggestions for how I can explain this in another way?

Comment: $$ n = 14 w + 10 = 7 (2w) + 10 = 7 (2w+1) +3 $$

Comment: When $n$ is divided by $10$ the remainder is $7$ (or $8$). What is the remainder when $n$ is divided by $5$? Undoubtedly the person has intuition plenty to deal with thst, and it might be a helpful beginning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't use fractions, instead use the usual [division algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division), note that every $7$ numbers, there is a multiple of $7$, ever $14$ a multiple of $14$, et cetera to motivate writing a number as

> $$n=14q+r$$

with $0\le r < 14$ each time. Then say every number is also of the form

> $$n=7q'+r'$$

with $0\le r'< 7$ and emphasize that clearly $r$ is unique. This is, of course, because you just count how many up you have to go from the nearest multiple of $7$, if you are $4$ more, then you are clearly not $3$ more.

If you like visuals you can demonstrate to the student with a simple list

$$\underbrace{\color{red}{0}}_{7\cdot 0},1,2,3,4,5,6,\underbrace{\color{red}{7}}_{7\cdot 1}, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, \underbrace{\color{red}{14}}_{7\cdot 2},\ldots$$

If the student knows enough about well-ordering, you can make this rigorous rather than simply intuitive since you can look at natural numbers of the form

> $$\{n-7k: k\in\Bbb Z\}$$

and just *define* $r$ to be the minimal element of this set.

From either approach, you can write

$$14q+10=7(2q+1)+3$$

so that $q'=2q+1$ and $r'=3$.

---

**Addendum:** If you want to emphasize how things are evenly space for the other remainders, you can make the same list with different highlighting, here I'll do $14$ and highlight the related $7$ information

> $$\underbrace{\color{red}{0}}_{14\cdot 0},1,2,\underbrace{\color{orange}{3}}_{7\cdot 1+3},4,5,6,7,8,9,\underbrace{\color{blue}{10}}_{14\cdot 0+10=7\cdot 1+3},11,12,13,\underbrace{\color{red}{14}}_{14\cdot 1},$$
>   $$15,16,\underbrace{\color{orange}{17}}_{7\cdot 2+3},18,19, 20,21,22,23,\underbrace{\color{blue}{24}}_{14\cdot 1+10=7\cdot 3+3},25,26,27,\underbrace{\color{red}{28}}_{14\cdot 2},$$
>   $$29,30,\underbrace{\color{orange}{31}}_{7\cdot 4+3},32,33,34,35,36,37,\underbrace{\color{blue}{38}}_{14\cdot 2+10=7\cdot 5+3},\ldots$$

This illustrates exactly how the $7q'+3$ numbers are distributed, and it's easy to see how they overlap with the $14q+10$ numbers every other one.

Comment: This approach makes good use of "algebra" in explanation.

Answer (score 4):

To motivate this to students who are just beginning to learn about remainders, it often helps to use real-world examples, e.g. if changing $\,n\,$ pennies (1 cent coins) into dimes (10 cent coins) leaves 8 cents, then changing these $\,n\,$ pennies into nickels (5 cent coins) leaves 3 cents, because we can first change them to dimes, then change each dime to 2 nickels, then change the remaining 8 pennies to 1 nickel and 3 pennies. Algebraically
$$\  n = 10q + 8\, =\, 5(2q) + 5 + 3\, =\, 5(2q+1) + 3$$

In modular language,  $\ {\rm mod}\,\ \color{}5\!:\ \begin{array}{r}\color{#c00}{10\equiv 0}\\ \color{#0a0}{8\equiv 3}\end{array}\,\ \Rightarrow\ \begin{array}{r}\color{#c00}{10}q+\color{#0a0}8\\ \,\equiv\ \color{#c00}0\,+\,\color{#0a0}3\end{array}\ $ by $ $  [Congruence Sum, Product Rules.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

Most students can easily visualize the money-changing. The goal is to help them translate that intuition into rigorous algebra, or, more powerfully, *congruence* algebra - as above.

Answer (score 2):

Colloquially (as I find sometimes works with my daughters at high school)

When we knock out $14$s the remainder is $10$. We knock out $7$s - well the $14$s all go because $14 = 2\times 7$ and we're left with $10=7+3$.

Comment: Of course use this to motivate general algebraic ideas ... that's the joy of teaching (today's lesson was exponential functions from scratch)

Answer (score 2):

$n=14k+10=7\cdot2\cdot k+7+3=(2k+1)7+3$, the remainder is $3$

Answer (score 0):

We have $n=14a+10$ for some integer $a$. If we take this equation modulo $7$ we have that $n \equiv 10 \mod 7 \equiv 3 \mod 7$ (This because $14 \equiv 0 \mod 7$ and $10 \equiv 3 \mod 7$). You should look up [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)
where you will see how to deal with this sort of questions. Modular arithmetic is very important in much branches of mathematics mostly in structures that have a finite number of elements in them (finite groups, rings, fields,...).

Answer (score 0):

It might help to go back to the basic definition of multiplication as repeated addition:

$$2 \cdot 5 = 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 10$$

and that division is the opposite of multiplication:
$$\frac{10}{2} \mapsto 10 \underbrace{{}- 2 - 2 - 2 - 2 - 2}_{\text{5 times}} = 0.$$
So $\frac{10}{2}=5$, remainder $0$

Also, for $\frac{11}{3} = \rightarrow 11 \underbrace{{}- 3 - 3 - 3}_{\text{3 times}} = 2$

So $\frac{11}{3}=3$, remainder $2=3+\frac{2}{3}$

If $\frac{n}{14}=a+\frac{10}{14}$, that means $n\underbrace{{}-14-14-14-\cdots}_{a\text{ times}}=10$

**Here's the simple/intuitive part:**

Since $2(7)=14$, division by 7 will also have a "remainder" of 10
But 10 > 7, so we can subtract out one more 7: $10 - 7 = 3$.
Therefore, the remainder ($r$) is 3: $r=3$
(Also note, $b=2a+1$.  Because $14=2(7)$, we double $a$.
Because we subtracted one more 7, we add 1.)